# Pull the value of a parent attribute based on it's child's value using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have some xml that I need to pull values from.  The very simplified version is as follows:

```
...
<event id="380783">
  ...
  <competitor id="1929" name="x">
    <homeaway>home</homeaway>
  </competitor>
  ...
</event>
...
```

There are many events and each one has a 'home' team and an 'away' team - I need to get the competitor id for home and for away, but I need to know which is which.

On its own, I can get the ID like so:

```
doc.xpath("//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor").attr('id').value
```

I can also find out whether a given node is 'home' or 'away'

```
2.1.1 :107 > first_match.xpath('//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway').children[0].text
 => "home" 
2.1.1 :108 > first_match.xpath('//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway').children[1].text
 => "away"
```

but I want to find the id scoped by whether it is home or away.  Something like:

```
away = xpath('//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway).children.text == away
away.parent.attr('id')
```

How could I do it?

Comment: Try `xpath('//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway[text()="away"]').parent.attr('id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (using `ancestor` axis to get `id` of `competitor`):

```
home_id = doc.at_xpath(
  "//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway[text()='home']" +
  "/ancestor::competitor/@id").value

away_id = doc.at_xpath(
  "//event[@id=#{uid}]//competitor//homeaway[text()='away']" +
  "/ancestor::competitor/@id").value
```

Answer (score 1):

Complicated xpaths are not needed:

xml2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>

<event id="380783">
  <competitor id="1929" name="x">
    <homeaway>home</homeaway>
  </competitor>

  <competitor id="1930" name="x">
    <homeaway>away</homeaway>
  </competitor>
</event>

<event id="380784">
  <competitor id="1931" name="x">
    <homeaway>away</homeaway>
  </competitor>

  <competitor id="1932" name="x">
    <homeaway>home</homeaway>
  </competitor>
</event>

</events>
```

...

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("xml2.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close

uid = 380784
event = doc.at_xpath("//event[@id=#{uid}]")
competitor_ids = {}

event.xpath('.//competitor').each do |competitor|
  id = competitor.attr('id').to_i
  homeaway = competitor.at_xpath('.//homeaway').text
  competitor_ids[id] = homeaway 
end

p competitor_ids

--output:--
{1931=>"away", 1932=>"home"}
```

And if needed, you can organize the whole xml file in a hash to make it simple to access the data in the way that you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = File.open("xml2.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close


events = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {}}

doc.xpath("//event").each do |event|
  event_id = event.attr('id').to_i

  event.xpath('.//competitor').each do |competitor|
    competitor_id = competitor.attr('id').to_i
    homeaway = competitor.at_xpath('.//homeaway').text
    events[event_id][homeaway] = competitor_id
  end
end

p events

uid = 380784
puts events[uid]['home']

--output:--
{380783=>{"home"=>1929, "away"=>1930}, 380784=>{"away"=>1931, "home"=>1932}}
1932
```